# When I have Foo.a.b.c.d, is there any way to know d is the last method in the chain?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

For `Foo.a.b.c.d`:

1. Can I get the entire chain somehow, e.g., `[:a,:b,:c,:d]`?
2. Is there any way to find out that `:d` is that last method call in the chain?

Comment: For your current question the answer is NO! But please explain where and why you want to do this.

Answer (score 5):

No. It is possible to find out who called a method. But it is impossible for a method to find out what will happen with its return value.

And thinking further. Having this

```
x = Foo.a.b.c
x.d
```

What should be last method in chain? `c` because it is the last chained method, or `d` because it it the last call on the returned value?

Comment: In other words, the question is unclear. It is not well defined.

Comment: OK, thought so. Closing this. Thanks for the responses.